# Selecting in nodes

Tags: animation, node-editor, selection-tools

How do I select the 4 things highlighted in green on the node like in the screenshot below. I’m trying to follow a tutorial on how to make an animation but when the guy selects those things on the map range I have no idea how he selected them. Can anyone tell me the key or command that allows me to select them.[image]

Comment: Hold the mouse down on the top one and drag it down over the others. **However** those colours mean that keyframes have been inserted on each value by hitting 'I' at one frame and I think those have to be inserted individually. Then the frame number has changed hence the green colour. Do you have a link to the tutorial with the time in the tutorial where the tutor was selecting them?